# C# Get All ActiveDirectory Users in DOMAIN\User format

Tags: c#, active-directory

This may be a dumb question but I am have never queried Active Directory Users before and I have no domain to do tests. So I have to test this snippet in a customer environment.  Right now, I have this code

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
{
    using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (Principal result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Principal Data");
            Console.WriteLine("Description: " + result.Description);
            Console.WriteLine("Display Name: " + result.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine("Distinguished Name: " + result.DistinguishedName);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + result.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("SAM Account Name: " + result.SamAccountName);
            Console.WriteLine("Structural Object Class: " + result.StructuralObjectClass);
            Console.WriteLine("User Principal Name: " + result.UserPrincipalName);
            Console.WriteLine("Context Data");
            Console.WriteLine("Connected Server: " + context.ConnectedServer);
            Console.WriteLine("Container: " + context.Container);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + context.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("UserName: " + context.UserName); 
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But I have not found the property that brings the users in DOMAINNAME\SAMUSERNAME format.  If I use for example:

```
string.Format("{0}\\{1}", context.Name, result.SamAccountName);
```

I get things like **domainname.local\samusername** but I want it like this **DOMAINNAME\SAMUSERNAME**.  I know I can do

```
string.Format("DOMAINNAME\\{0}", result.SamAccountName);
```

but I dont want it to be hardcoded.

Also I am not sure that using

```
string.Format("{0}\\{1}", context.Name.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].ToUpper(), result.SamAccountName);
```

will work for any scenario.

This is for a Membership User administration page, the user list will let the  administrator to select and then add membership roles to the user.  I know I will need to add search functionality but right now I am justing trying to get the basic result and then add the fancy things.

What I want is something more generic that can be used in any scenario. How can this be done.

Hope anyone can give me some lights. Thanks in advance.

Regards